# How to iterate a list and show in drop down in jsp

Tags: html, jsp, struts-1

I have some data in my list and I am trying to add those in a dropdown list .I am trying to iterate the list and adding in the dropdown. But I am not getting the proper result .
Below are my code can anybody please help me out.

```
<select>    
    <logic:iterate name="CMSSetupForm" property="configListMetaData"        id="configVO" type="com.infores.mdm.ui.domainobjects.cms.ConfigurationVO"  indexId="indid">
    <option value="<bean:write name="configVO" property="attributeGroup"/>">
   </option>

  </logic:iterate>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSTL for this

[Here is a nice tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)

You can use forEach of core taglib like this -

```
<c:forEach items="${names}" var="name">
    <option value="${name}">${name}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Assuming names is a List of String like this -

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```